# How to make tensorflow object detection faster-r cnn model work on Android?

Tags: android, python, tensorflow, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I have a question about [Tensorflows Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). I trained  [Faster R-CNN Inception v2 model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) with my own dataset for Traffic Sign Classification and I want to deploy it to Android but [Tensorflows Object Detection API for Android](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android) and/or [Tensorflow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite) seems only supporting SSD models.

Is there any way to deploy a Faster R-CNN model to Android? I mean how can I put my frozen inference graph of Faster R-CNN to android API instead of SSDs frozen inference graph ?

Comment: where you able to determine if faster_rcnn is supported now in tflite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For SSD models, it must be possible using the `export_tflite_ssd_graph.py` tool. But:

> At this time only SSD models are supported. Models like faster_rcnn
>   are not supported at this time

See [this guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_mobile_tensorflowlite.md) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is by making a **flask** **API**, which will contain all the code for making prediction for a given image, and post it to a **remote server** such as **Heroku**. You can call the API by simply converting the image to **Base64** or 32 from Android and sending it to the **REST API** deployed on Heroku. The API will compute the result (inference) and convert the output image back to  Base64 and send it back to Android app. The android app will convert Base64 to bitmap and Walah! you made your prediction.
You can use either **HttpConnection** library or just **Retrofit** for remote API calls in Android